# Unable to directly load hive parquet table using spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have gone thru related posts available in SO and couldn't find this specific issue anywhere over the internet.

I am trying to load Hive table (Hive external table pointed to parquet files) but spark data frame couldn't read the data and it is just able to read schema. But for the same hive table i can query from hive shell. When i try to load hive table into dataframe it is not returning any data. Below is my script looks like and the DDL. I am using Spark 2.1 (Mapr distribution)

Unable to read data from hive table has underlying parquet files from spark

```
val df4 = spark.sql("select * from default.Tablename")
scala> df4.show()
+----------------------+------------------------+----------+---+-------------+-------------+---------+
|col1           |col2           |col3                       |key            |col4|  record_status|source_cd|
+----------------------+------------------------+----------+---+-------------+-------------+---------+
+----------------------+------------------------+----------+---+-------------+-------------+---------+

Hive DDL
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `Tablename`(
  `col1` string,
  `col2` string,
  `col3` decimal(19,0),
  `key` string,
  `col6` string,
  `record_status` string,
  `source_cd` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'path'='maprfs:abc/bds/dbname.db/Tablename')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'maprfs:/Datalocation/Tablename'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'numFiles'='2',
  'spark.sql.sources.provider'='parquet',
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"col1\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"col2\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"col3\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"key\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"col6\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"record_status\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"source_cd\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}',
  'totalSize'='68216',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1502904476')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove 
'spark.sql.sources.provider'='parquet'
and you will success

Comment: Yes that solved the problem and working fine.Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to remove this property?

Comment: This property was there in my ddl(create table statement), i have deleted this line and fixed that issue. Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue in accessing parquet file from hive.